# Error thrown with bundling Puppeteer for Chrome Extension

Tags: installation, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I'm currently trying to follow the [instructions](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/6522e4f524bdbc1f1b9d040772acf862517ed507/utils/browser) to bundle puppeteer for integration with my Chrome Extension project where I'm going to be web scraping a page for locations and displaying it on a map using leaflet. However, I keep running into trouble with the set up process. Currently I'm stuck on step 2 and 3 of the process. When running `npm install` in the `\puppeteer` folder created by the `git clone https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer && cd puppeteer` command it returns.

```
Puppeteer: Compiling TypeScript...
Error running TypeScript Error: Command failed: npm run tsc
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@5.2.1-post clean-lib: `rm -rf lib`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.2.1-post clean-lib script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T21_57_06_630Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@5.2.1-post tsc: `npm run clean-lib && tsc --version && npm run tsc-cjs && npm run tsc-esm`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.2.1-post tsc script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T21_57_06_646Z-debug.log

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npm run tsc',
  stdout: '\n' +
'> puppeteer@5.2.1-post tsc C:\\Users\\username\\node_modules\\puppeteer\n' +
'> npm run clean-lib && tsc --version && npm run tsc-cjs && npm run tsc-esm\n' +
'\n' +
'\n' +
'> puppeteer@5.2.1-post clean-lib C:\\Users\\username\\node_modules\\puppeteer\n' +
'> rm -rf lib\n' +
'\n',
  stderr: "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.\r\n' +
    'npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\n' +
    'npm ERR! errno 1\n' +
    'npm ERR! puppeteer@5.2.1-post clean-lib: `rm -rf lib`\n' +
    'npm ERR! Exit status 1\n' +
    'npm ERR! \n' +
    'npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.2.1-post clean-lib script.\n' +
    'npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n' +
    '\n' +
    'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
    'npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2020-08-31T21_57_06_630debug.log\n' +
'npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\n' +
'npm ERR! errno 1\n' +
'npm ERR! puppeteer@5.2.1-post tsc: `npm run clean-lib && tsc --version && npm run tsc-cjs && npm run tsc-esm`\n' +
'npm ERR! Exit status 1\n' +
'npm ERR! \n' +
'npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.2.1-post tsc script.\n' +
'npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n' +
'\n' +
'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
'npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2020-08-31T21_57_06_646Z-debug.log\n'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@5.2.1-post install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.2.1-post install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

and also when `npm run bundle` is run it says `missing script:bundle.js`

I am running all of these on Windows 10, I have Node v12.18.3 and npm v6.14.6 installed.

I have browserify installed however I have yet to use it. Do I need to set anything else up? Also if there is a better alternative to web scraping on a Chrome Extension please let me know.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: that is happening to me, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer` When you execute this command it will download the newest version of Puppeteer.

The problem occurs because the newest version of Puppeteer is missing some old commands & files. That was existing back when the tutorial has been made.

---

### More explantion:

- **Typescript Error:**
  You need to install typescript in npm [I found it here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling)
- **Bundling Error:**
  This is a screenshot from *package.json* file version 5.5.0:
  [package.json version 5.5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMmdG.jpg)
  This is a screenshot from *package.json* file version 2.1.1:
  [package.json version 2.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYhqr.jpg)
  You will see that `"scripts":{"bundle":"bundle": "npx browserify -r ./install.js:puppeteer -o utils/browser/puppeteer-web.js"}` in the newset version. When you try to execute `npm run bundle` it will found nothing to execute. This is a small example of missing things. As general there is a big differenece between the two versions of course.

---

### Solution:

I believe this is a temporary solution cause we are missing a lot of updates.Also I'm working on another solution to use the bundled newest version. I will update my anser once I reach it.

- So you have to download the old version of Puppeteer manually:
  [Download Puppeteer version 2.1.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/archive/6522e4f524bdbc1f1b9d040772acf862517ed507.zip)
- After downloading this version go to its folder and execute the commands:

  1. `npm install -g typescript`
  2. `npm install`
  3. `npm run bundle`